# outward or inward sin

Tags: vocabulary

An action that is seen is called apparent or visible, right?

I was comparing two things and had a halt on what word fits best here.

Robbing is an offence that is seen. Keeping malice is also an offence but isn't seen. What word best fits here?

'outward sin’ OR ‘apparent sin':  for an offence like robbing

'inward sin’ OR ‘hidden sin':    for an offence like keeping malice

Or what about 'external sin' & ‘internal sin’?

Comment: "*Robbing is an offence that is seen*". Not if you're good at it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use apparent and hidden sin.

External and internal can be confused with referring to others/self, so sin towards others or sin towards self. Rather than whether it's shown or not.